# How do I progressively load a widget in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a custom widget which displays many items in rows:

```
void update(){ //this is a SLOT which is connected to a button click
    QVBoxLayout *layout = this->layout();
    if (layout == NULL){
        layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        this->setLayout(layout);
    } else {
        QLayout_clear(layout); //this is a function that I wrote that deletes all of the items from a layout
    }
    ArrayList *results = generateData(); //this generates the data that I load from
    for (int i = 0; i < results->count; i++){
        layout->addWidget(new subWidget(results->array[i]));
    }
}
```

The problem is that there are about 900 items and a profile reveals that simply adding the child object to the layout takes 50% of the time (constructing takes the other 50%). Overall it takes about 3 seconds to load all of the items.

When I click on the button to load more data, the entire UI freezes for the 3 seconds and then all of the items appear together when everything is done. Is there a way to progressively load more items as they are being created?

Comment: This sounds to me like the producer/consumer model. You could do the object creation/processing in another thread and use signals to notify the main thread that there are more objects to show.

Comment: @AdriC.S. GUI elements can only be created on the GUI thread. The `generateData` function accounts for only 5% of the load time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first trick is, as Pavel Zdenek said, to process only some of the results. You want to process as many together so that the overhead (of what we're going to do in the next step) is low, but you don't want to do anything that would make the system seem unresponsive. Based on extensive research, [Jakob Nielsen says that](http://www.useit.com/papers/responsetime.html) "0.1 seconds is about the limit for having the user feel that the system is reacting instantaneously", so as a rough estimate you should cut your work into roughly 0.05 second chunks (leaving another 0.05 seconds for the system to actually react to the user's interactions).

The second trick is to use a `QTimer` with a timeout of 0. As the [QTimer documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtimer.html) says:

> As a special case, a QTimer with a timeout of 0 will time out as soon
>   as all the events in the window system's event queue have been
>   processed. This can be used to do heavy work while providing a snappy
>   user interface.

So that means that a timer with a timeout of 0 will be executed next, unless there is something else in the event queue (for instance, a mouse click). Here's the code:

```
void update() {
    i = 0; // warning, this is causes a bug, see below
    updateChunk();
}

void updateChunk() {
    const int CHUNK_THRESHOLD = /* the number of things you can do before the user notices that you're doing something */;
    for (; i < results->count() && i < CHUNK_THRESHOLD; i++) {
         // add widget
    }
    // If there's more work to do, put it in the event queue.
    if (i < results->count()) {
        // This isn't true recursion, because this method will return before
        // it is called again.
        QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(updateChunk()));
    }
}
```

Finally, test this a little bit because there's a gotcha: now the user can interact with the system in the "middle" of your loop. For instance, the user can click the update button while you're still processing results (which in the above example means that you would reset the index to 0 and reprocess the first elements of the array). So a more robust solution would be to use a list instead of an array and pop each element off the front of the list as you process it. Then whatever adds results would just append to the list.

Comment: Yes, but if the user clicks on a button, you dont want to continue loading old data. Is there a way of detecting "the user did something" without connecting to every signal? Other than that, this works splendidly!

Comment: If the new data replaces old data (instead of adding to it), just clear out your results and process the new data.

Answer (score 2):

@Adri is generally right, the twist is that the "another thread" must be the UI thread again. The point is to allow UI thread's event loop to keep spinning. The fast and dirty way is to put `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` in your `for()` cycle. Dirty because, as [the doc says](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents), it should be called "ocassionally". It might have some overhead even if there are no UI events, and you are messing Qt's performance optimization as to when and how often spin the loop. Slightly less dirty would be to call it only ocassionally, after chunks of `result`.

Cleaner and proper way is to create a private slot, which pops one result element (or chunk, to speed up), adds to the layout and increments index. Then it will recall itself until end of `results`. The gotcha is to define `connect()` with forced connection type `Qt::QueuedConnection`, so it will get deferred after already queued UI events (if any).

And because you run in only one thread, you don't need any locking over `results`.

**Adding example per OP's request:**

While @TomPanning solution is correct, it kind of hides the real solution behind QTimer which you don't need - you don't need any timing, you just need a specific non-timer behavior upon specific parameter value. This solution does the same thing, minus the QTimer layer. On the other hand, @TomPanning has a very good point about the plain ArrayList not being very good data storage, when interaction can happen in between.

`something.h`

```
signals: void subWidgetAdded();
private slots: void addNextWidget();
ArrayList* m_results;
int m_indexPriv;
```

`something.cpp`

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(subWidgetAdded()),
        this,SLOT(addNextWidget(),
        Qt::QueuedConnection);

void addWidget() {
  // additional chunking logic here as you need
  layout->addWidget(new subWidget(results->array[m_indexPriv++]));
  if( m_indexPriv < results->count() ) {
    emit subWidgetAdded(); // NOT a recursion :-)
  }
}

void update() {
  // ...
  m_results = generateData();
  m_indexPriv = 0;
  addNextWidget(); // slots are normal instance methods, call for the first time
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate a little more on how to do it properly? when you mention `connect` are you talking about the connect from the button to add data? If the slot is recursive, how is that different from loading all the items iteratively as I am already doing?